# Nodejs (socket.io) memory usage compared to JavaScript's primitive data type memory usage

Tags: node.js

First off, my title may be poorly defined or misleading, but it pretty much tries to summarize my question as a whole.

I've searched a lot without getting my questions fully answered.

1. How does socket.io memory allocation through MemoryStorage (socket.get/socket.set) work and how much memory usage does approximately one socket.set use? Are memory freed correctly when a socket disconnects? Optional: Is there any known memory leaks I should be aware of in v0.11.0-pre?
2. How does JavaScript's GarbageCollector work with objects and associative arrays declared in global scope? Are memory ultimately freed When I "delete" a key-value pair like this: "delete object[key];"? Or will RAM continuely increase as client requests increase?
3. How are option 1 and 2 compared to each other? Should I use socket.set over globally declared "maps" when it comes to increasing and ultimately freeing memory? Optional: How are they compared to each other when it comes to performance ("executing" socket.get/object[key])?

As for basic information on my project, I'm developing a game server in Node.js (single process) which are expected to accept as many clients as a single server can handle (before extending to a cluster of servers). Optional: Is there something else regarding my project I should be aware of when it comes to load and memory??

Thank you for your time, it is much appreciated!

Comment: As a self-update to this issue:
In Socket.io 1.0.X socket.set and socket.get is deprecated. As for socket memory usage, my qustion still stands.
I also found out that there is no explicit deletion in JavaScript, delete does not free the memory, merely deletes the reference.